# git keeps pushing files that are listed in .gitignore

Tags: git

So I have a video folder in my repository that contains some files with `.mp4` extension. So I've added them to `.gitignore` like this:

*.gitignore:*

`.mp4`

And If I understood all correctly it should ignore all files with `.mp4` extension. But it doesn't.

I've made next procedure:

```
git rm -r --cached .

git add .

git commit -m "fixing .gitignore"

git push repositoryname master
```

But it still pushing my `.mp4` files.

How can I fix it?

p.s. My `.gitignore` file is located inside root folder of my project, not inside `.git` folder

p.s.s. I've added `*.mp4` but problem still occurs, here are the logs:

```
PS C:\inetpub\wwwroot\utg> git rm -r --cached .;git add .;git commit -m 'gitignore';git push utgpage mas
rm '.gitignore'
rm '.project'
rm 'README.md'
rm 'css/bounce.css'
rm 'css/parallax.css'
rm 'fonts/airbrne2.ttf'
rm 'img/logo_white_common.png'
rm 'img/overlay-pattern.png'
rm 'img/utg_logo_white.png'
rm 'index.php'
rm 'js/script.js'
rm 'js/smooth.js'
rm 'video/vid1.mp4'
rm 'video/vid2.mp4'
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in css/bounce.css.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in index.php.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in js/script.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in js/smooth.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
[master 59dcc7f] gitignore
 3 files changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
 delete mode 100644 video/vid1.mp4
 delete mode 100644 video/vid2.mp4
Counting objects: 81, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (71/71), done.
Writing objects: 100% (72/72), 129.33 MiB | 311.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 72 (delta 37), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected.
remote: error: Trace: 863068061510dfca317ad799de2a9cad
remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.
remote: error: File video/vid2.mp4 is 129.55 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
To https://github.com/Tachii/utg-frontpage.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to '****'
```

Comment: Have you looked here: https://help.github.com/articles/working-with-large-files/ ? Github requires additional space to be available and you can't push files larger than 100 MB and I believe yours is 130 MB.

Comment: I'd also like to point out that if you're having trouble it would be worth running the commands one at a time rather than blindly pushing without taking the time to verify that you are committing or pushing the correct files.

Comment: @TheOnlyError I know that it doesn't files > 100MB, that's why i'm using .gitignore that isn't working.

Comment: @nthall I was doing it, and when I was commiting changes, and using ```git status``` it was not showing ```video``` folder. But then again it still was pushing it...

Comment: What if you try to put it in the .git (repository) directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By specifying `.mp4` in your .gitignore file, you are simply instructing Git to ignore either a file or folder named '.mp4'. 
To ignore all files ending with '.mp4', you need to add a wildcard operator which in this case is an asterisk. So in your .gitignore file, use `*.mp4` and all files with a name ending with .mp4 will be ignored.

Answer (score 3):

Try this putting an Asterisk in front of it:

```
*.mp4
```

Check this link for more info about gitignore: http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

Answer (score 3):

If you want to ignore all mp4 files, I believe the .gitignore line would be:

`*.mp4`